# Coupled ODEs with parameters subject to optimization problem

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization

I have an equation, but I don’t know how to program it in *Mathematica*:

```
x[0]==1; y[0]==1; x'[t]==(a+b) x[t] y[t]; y'[t]==a b y[t]/x[t];
```

where `a`, `b` are numerical solution of optimization problem, or system of algebraic equations:

```
Maximize[{3a^0.8b^0.2+a^2/(a-x)+b^2/(b-y)}, {a, b}]
```

If there had been an exact solution for `a`, `b` it would be possible to plug their values into the differential equation, but in this case, first the magnitudes of `a` and `b` are calculated, and only then derivatives are determined.

Comment: I guess I cannot help you unless you specify what x' mean? D[x[t],t]? D[x[a],a]? ??

Comment: Since `x` and `y` are functions of `t` as well as of `a` and `b`, it seems to me that `Maximize` must be done with respect to `{a, b, t}`.  Is that your intent?

Comment: Note also that the quantity to be `Maximize`d becomes infinite as `t` approaches `Log[(a^2 (1 + b))/(a + b)]/(a + b + a b)` or `Log[(a b^2)/(a + b - b^2)]/(a + b + a b)`.

Comment: I am not sure but as x[0] and y[0] are given you can calculate a[x[0]] and b[x[0]]. So if you discretize your differential system of equations you can obtain x[0+h],y[0+h] and then use those two values to calculate a[x[h]], b[x[h]] and so on. In choosing a small gap h you certainly approach the solution. If you cannot manage it I will try later

Comment: Sounds like this could be formulated as a DAE, with the gradient used in the associated algebraic equations.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd like to point out the function you chose for optimization doesn't have a finite maximum:

```
With[{k = 10^20}, 
 Plot3D[3 a^(8/10) b^(2/10) + a^2/(a - x) + b^2/(b - y) /. x | y -> 1 // 
   Evaluate, {a, -k, k}, {b, -k, k}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Still, generally it's possible to do what you want, here I'll use

```
Maximize[-(a - Sin[x])^2 - (b - Sin[y])^2, {a, b}]
(* {0, {a -> Sin[x], b -> Sin[y]}} *)
```

as an example. As you can see this optimization problem has an symbolic solution so we can easily check if the obtained solution is correct.

Back to our problem, what we need is just a black box function:

```
blackbox[{x_?NumericQ, y_}] := 
 Module[{a, b}, {a, b} = NArgMax[-(a - Sin[x])^2 - (b - Sin[y])^2, {a, b}]; {(a + b) x y,
    a b y/x}]

solxy = NDSolveValue[{xy'[t] == blackbox[xy@t], xy[0] == {1, 1}}, 
    xy, {t, 0, 1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {3.044525, Null} *)

{solx, soly} = 
 ListInterpolation[#, Flatten@solxy["Grid"]] & /@ Transpose@solxy["ValuesOnGrid"];

(* Result for comparison *)
{solx2, soly2} = 
 NDSolveValue[{x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1, x'[t] == (a + b) x[t] y[t], 
    y'[t] == a b y[t]/x[t]} /. 
   Last@Maximize[-(a - Sin[x@t])^2 - (b - Sin[y@t])^2, {a, b}], {x, y}, {t, 0, 1}];

Plot[{solx@t, soly@t, solx2@t, soly2@t}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Dashed}, {Thick, Dashed}, Thin, Thin}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

## Update

Just saw your comment under Chris' answer. With the constraint `0 < a < 1, 0 < b < 1` there's indeed a finite maximum. Then we just need to define the black box function as:

```
blackbox[{x_?NumericQ, y_}] := 
 Module[{a, b}, {a, b} = 
   NArgMax[{3 a^(8/10) b^(2/10) + a^2/(a - x) + b^2/(b - y), 0 < a < 1, 0 < b < 1}, {a, 
     b}]; {(a + b) x y, a b y/x}]
```

Rest part of the code is unchanged. The obtained result is:

```
Plot[{solx[t], soly[t]}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

### This is not an answer but a comment

How about

```
 {X,Y}=DSolveValue[{x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1, x'[t] == (a + b) x[t] y[t],
    y'[t] == a b y[t]/x[t]}, {x, y}, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then you can specify *a posteriori* your values for `a` and `b`?

### Update

oops I had not seen that your optimization problem involves 'x,y'…

Comment: well, maximize 3a^0.8b^0.2+a^2/(a-1)+b^2/(b-1) in 0<=x<=0.99999, 0<=y<=0.99999 returns in a compact set a=0.43917, b=0.27115. Further, we get derivatives x', y', and attain a new state of the system, and once again calculate a, b via optimization. since for every x,y there is a unique solution (a,b), global extreme, it may be said a=f(x,y),b=g(x,y). here a question arises, do we know derivatives? - yes, do we have initial values? - yes. thus there should be an integral curve.